# How to change useState's state without re-rendering the component, but just its components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How do I change the useState without re-rendering it but just its components? Why I need is because I have some logic that changes the useState in Comp1. If I would re-render Comp1 I would have to recalculate its value. But if the change happens I still would like to re-render its components.

Edit: bigger code snippet.

```
function Comp1() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (_user) {
    if (_user) {
      // User is signed in.
      setUser(_user);
    } else {
      setUser({ exists: false });
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <UserProvider.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
        <Comp2 />
        <Comp3 />
      </UserProvider.Provider>

    </div>
  );
}

function Comp2(props) {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserProvider);
  return (
    <div>
      {user.exists}
    </div>
  )
}

function Comp3(props) {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserProvider);
  return (
    <div>
      {user.exists}
    </div>
  )
}

//User Provider

import React from 'react';

const UserProvider = React.createContext();
export default UserProvider;
```

Comment: You can use [React.memo](https://scotch.io/tutorials/react-166-reactmemo-for-functional-components-rendering-control) to determine when your components will update based on their old/new state.  However, if the state is actually being changed and used in the components, it will have to re-render to reflect that change.  If you aren't using ```state``` in Comp1, why not move it into ```Comp2```?

Comment: If you are worried that the calculation would take time, you can `memoize` the calculation result.

Comment: I tried to simplifed the example. I do use state in Comp1, I need it there. How do I use memo for this purpose?

Comment: React is designed a way that when your state or props are changed it rerenders a component. But, there an option like `shouldComponentUpdate` or `memo`, where you can tweak it a bit. You can pass a custom comparison function to the `memo` as second argument.

Comment: I have a Firebase OAuthChange function set up in  Comp1 so when the change happens It shares the state through useContext.

Comment: It sounds like a candidate to `useEffect`.

Comment: I'm confused :(

Comment: Can you share a bit more complete example?

Comment: It would be too long, but I try to reflect on what I have in a bit detailed code example.

Comment: I extended it. If something is uncleary let me know.

Comment: Can you add the things you're calculating in `Comp2`? Or an example? I think that would make it easier to answer this question and explain how to use `useEffect` or `memo`. Also why not pass user as a prop instead of context?

Comment: I edited it, so now it shows, that I need user in multiple components. I did not add the calculation in the code snippet, but why I need it to be only in one component is because I use some firestrore queries to add properties to user.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156#issuecomment-474590693)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a shot at answering your question. Basically, you want to be able to calculate a value once and have it updated only when the content changes. You can do this with `useEffect`. The first parameter for `useEffect` is a function you want to happen on mount/update. It should return a function to run when your function is unmounted (if any). The second argument are the things that determine if `useEffect` gets ran. I put it to run when `user` changes value. Hopefully this is enough to get you started down the path of something. You can read more about `useEffect` in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

```
function Comp2(props) {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserProvider);
  const { state, setState } = useState({ value: '' });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(user);
    // perform expensive operation
    setValue({ value: 'My expensive operation is now stored' });
    return () => {
      // Do you have anything that you would put in componentWillUnmount()?
      // Put that here
    };
  }, [user]);

 console.log(state.value);

  return (
    <div>
      {user.exists}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it out tomorrow. Tuday I'm just too tired.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to ditch the **useContext** hooks as they seem to cause re-renders on components they're attached to.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).